# Cannot access array values using a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving an array from an `HTML` form.

```
var parts=req.body.parts
```

Doing `console.log(parts)` returns an array:

```
['Part1','Part2']
```

However, for some reason the `console.log(parts[i])` returns `undefined`.

However, if I change the value to `console.log(parts[0])`, I get `[Part1]` as my output.

```
let loop= parts.length
for(i=0;i<loop;i++){
        console.log(i)
        console.log(parts[i])

    }
```

I cannot figure out why this is happening

Comment: The variable is `parts`, not `partNumber`.

Comment: This is rare, appears to be related on a typo with the variable name (`parts` vs `partNumber`), but he also says that: `console.log(partNumber[0])` gives some output. So It will be nicely to see a minimal working example showing the issue.

Comment: I agree, the question is a little vague so far

Comment: Sorry Edited the question it was subbosed to be `parts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few issues here:

1. You are using the variables `parts` and `partNumber`. They should be the same
2. You never declared `i` in your for loop, it should look like this:

```
const parts = req.body.parts;

for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    // do whatever

    console.log(i, parts[i]);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue was not declaring `i` in the for loop